# Character datatype from C language

Tags: c

What is the meaning of -128 to 127 in Character datatype in C language. Is that any kind of Range in which we can write characters or not AND also Why are we using here -(minus) Sign?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. `char` is an integer type. If it is signed or unsigned by default is implementation-specific as is its range. What is your point?

Comment: What is the meaning of -32768 to 32767 in short datatype in C language? Why are we using here -(minus) sign?

Answer (score 1):

Characters are represented by a single byte. A byte typically represents a range of 0-255 unique values.

You can have signed or unsigned chars, they are equivalent as their integer representation is not important (for actual characters). The unsigned mapping of 0-255 becomes -128 to 127. Many compilers choose signed by default, however there is no standard as to what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joseph but i want to know about of -128 why are we using here Minus(-) Sign

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. By default, characters in C are signed, meaning they can have negative and positive values. I assume this is just to align with ints also having negative and positive values. 

The reason why they did this is because chars are not only used for characters.

They are often used also for small numbers, and representations of binary, as they are a byte

Comment: Thanks  Joseph young

Comment: @JosephYoung: `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned` by default.  Many compilers choose the `signed` default for historical reasons.  On early C implementations, there was no `signed` keyword, so `char` was signed to support 8-bit ints with signed semantics.  Signed `char` by default is actually inconsistent with many C library functions: `isspace(c)` invokes undefined behavior if `c` is a signed `char` with value `\200`.

Comment: @chqrlie: `char` is not generally signed. On ARM, e.g. AAPCS enforces it to be unsigned by default. This for historical reasons, as there was only a zero-extend byte-load in early versions. Similar for MSP430. For other CPUs the opposite might be true, so their `char` is signed by default. If the CPU has symmetric loads or can operate on 8 bit registers, it might be because of rolled dice, though.

Comment: 1) "a byte can only have 0-255 unique values" - No; an octet can have 256 different values. What they represent is a matter of semantics. The number of values a byte might hold depends on the number of bits in the byte. An 9 bit byte can hold 512 values for instance. 2) `char` is not signed by default! See my comment above for two architectures which have unsigned char.

Comment: @Olaf: thank you for these extra precisions, the default for ARM architectures makes sense, I actually don't know if the original PDPs had only sign extended byte load semantics, but it is unfortunate that `char` be signed by default on so many systems where no such constraint can justify this choice.

Comment: @chqrlie: I actually wish `char` was a true character type like in Modula/Pacsal, etc. However, one can argue a default signed `char` is somewhat more straight, because C does prefere signed integers in general (promotions, _character constants_ which are `int`, too). Good practise is to use explicitly specify `(un)signed char` if integer semantics are use and `char` only where character semantics are used. But actually, when using small integers `stdint.h` types are most times the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the builtin `char` type has 1 Byte = 8 bits of storage. So it can represent 2^8 = 256 unique values.

- An `unsigned char` can represent numbers 0 through 255.
- A `signed char` (or just `char`) can represent numbers -128 through 127.

Characters like 'a', 'B', '7', and '&' are all assigned a number 0 through 127 called an ascii code (see http://www.asciitable.com), so the negative numbers representable by a char are not used when dealing with ascii characters.

Edit: note that a `char` is not guaranteed to have this many bytes, this is just a common implementation (thanks M.M)

Comment: Thanks Dylan for your answer but could you tell me what is the meaning of -128 in the size representation of the Char Datatype

Comment: It is the lowest representable value in a `signed char` (if you subtract one from `signed char` -128, you will wrap around and get a result of 127).  This is called integer underflow.  So yes it is a range.

Comment: Your description is a common implementation but it is not universal.  Another common setup is that `char` is unsigned and has range `0` through `255`.  A few systems have `char` being 32-bit or other sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @M.M - edited.

Comment: `char` is guaranteed to be exactly one byte.  a byte is not garanteed to be 8 bits, t may be more than 8 bits.  `char` is not necessarily signed, it is just a common compiler default.

Comment: I can see this answer is trying to be useful, but it's riddled with technical errors. chqrlie mentioned two, but here's some more. Even if a signed char has 8 bits, it's not guaranteed that it can represent -128. An unsigned char can represent at least 256 unique values (not 255). Subtracting one from (signed char)-128 does not give 127: integer promotions cause the addition to be done in int rather than signed char, and assigning the result back to a signed char variable is undefined behavior unless it can represent the value -129.

Comment: An octet (i.e. a byte with 8 bits) can hold `2**8 == 256` different values, not **`255`**. And `char` is not necessarily signed. That is implementation defined. The wide-spread ARM architecture e.g. uses unsigned `char` by the PCS/ABI,